# Upgrading AWS Aurora MySQL outside of available maintenance windows

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, upgrade, amazon-aurora, sql-update

I created an AWS Aurora (MySQL) cluster and AWS automatically provisioned the following versions for me:

```
MySQL [myapp_db]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| aurora_version          | 1.16                         |
| innodb_version          | 1.2.10                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.6.10                       |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

I'd like to upgrade this DB to MySQL 5.7.x. According to [their upgrade docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.html) it *looks* like you can only do this if/when they open up an available maintenance window.

**I'm wondering if any battle-weary AWS veterans know of any way I can do this upgrade?**

---

#### Update

This is what I see when I go into the **Cluster Actions** menu:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always upgrade manually instead of waiting for a maintenance window. From the Aurora cluster display in the AWS console you can select your cluster, then click "Cluster actions", then select "Upgrade Now" to trigger the upgrade process.

That being said, at this time MySQL 5.7 compatibility for Aurora is still [in preview](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/12/announcing-preview-of-amazon-aurora-with-mysql-5-7-compatibility/). Have you requested to be added to the preview already? I'm not sure what the upgrade path would be but since it isn't a finalized version yet I would seriously recommend taking a snapshot of your current database, and creating a new cluster that is upgraded to MySQL 5.7 compatibility, and then testing that well before switching any important production loads over to that.

Comment: Thanks @Mark B (+1) - please see my screenshot that I added above. That's what I see when I go to the RDS dashboard. If I click on **Clusters** and select my cluster, then on the following screen I see a lot of cluster information but I do *not* see a **Cluster Actions** menu/option anywhere on the screen. If I click on an instance inside my cluster, I do see an **Instance Actions** menu, but no options from there regarding upgrading. Any ideas? Thanks again so much!

Comment: @smeeb on the left side of that page in your screen, click Clusters,then on the cluster page select the cluster (radio button), then near the very top of the page there should be a Cluster Actions button. You should also be able to simply right-click the cluster to get the cluster actions menu.

Comment: Ahh thanks @Mark B (+1 again!), I was able to find the **Cluster Actions** menu, but please see my update above: *Upgrade Now* is disabled! Any ideas as to why?!

Comment: @smeeb probably because there aren't any pending updates? Have you applied for the MySQL 5.7 preview for Aurora already?

Comment: Ahhh that was the missing link, didn't realize it was something you needed to apply for, thanks!